# I need a backend system that is integrated with web services, is there an open source solution?

Tags: web-services, open-source, mobile-application

I'm basically familiar with what I need in order to setup web services to talk with a centralized db, but if I don't have to go through and do all the work, I'd rather not.

Is there an open source solution that would allow me to easily integrate web services for data transfer to a central db?

I want to make a site that is powered by a db that can also be accessed by other things like mobile apps for example.

What are the steps involved in setting up such a site?

Any help is appreciated! I could use all the help I can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah I'm going to have to agree here with Chris -- that's a lot of work with no simple solution. If you're looking for a single server and database to host your data, which can be accessed by a website, mobile application, etc, it **can** be done but carries a lot of **work** and connecting things together. To my knowledge there is nothing that sets things up for you.

I'd recommend looking into **frameworks** for your language (**CakePHP**, **Ruby on Rails**, etc) to build up the database and web app, then create mobile apps that pull and interact with the data from XML files or some other source of relaying the data to your mobile device.

If I took your question in the right way, this is my recommendation on having a single database house your data which can be maintained and accessed through a website and mobile app. I've done this with a previous app and it worked fantastically on all ends. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Considering a web service is a bit of code that is custom per application.. I'm going to go out on a limb here and say: No.

Answer (score 0):

A fully open source backend solution could be [Deployd](http://deployd.com) and with [DeploydKit](https://github.com/clooket/DeploydKit) or [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) you could build an iOS app, there are probably libraries also for Android.